# Extending CrudRepository, select all from one column?

Tags: java, spring, repository, crud

I'm working on a simple Spring app. Trying to create an interface that extends from Crud Repository. I'm having trouble creating a method that just selects one column.

I have a 'Dog' model. Here's my interface, which includes a method which is supposed to select all my dog breeds:

```java
public interface DogRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT breed FROM dog", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Dog> retrieveDogBreeds();
}
```

Which gives me error:

```
could not execute query; SQL [SELECT breed FROM dog]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

I can select * with no problem:

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dog", nativeQuery = true)
```

^That returns everything on my table.

Here's my service:

```java
@Service
public class DogServiceImpl implements DogService{
    @Autowired
    DogRepository dogRepository;

    public List<Dog> retrieveDogs() {
        return (List<Dog>)dogRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Dog> retrieveDogBreeds(){
        return (List<Dog>)dogRepository.retrieveDogBreeds();
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```java
@RestController
public class DogController {
    private DogService dogService;

    @Autowired
    public void setDogService(DogService dogService) {
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/dog")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Dog>> getAllDogs() {
        List<Dog> list = dogService.retrieveDogs();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Dog>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/dog/breeds")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Dog>> getAllBreeds() {
        List<Dog> list = dogService.retrieveDogBreeds();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Dog>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by changing my syntax:

```java
public interface DogRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Long> {
    @Query("select d.breed from Dog d")
    List<String> findAllBreed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest try the above the Dog Repository class with @Table annotation since you are using SpringBoot. I am not sure it works but i had same exception issues `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` . So, wanted to share